# Differentiability of product/composition of function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

How will be the product and composition of two functions, where one is differentiable and another is just continuous, behave?I mean to say, if the product or composition is differentiable, then what are the conditions on the functions to hold for their product to be differentiable, if they are?

Some trivial checks: Of course, the product/composition is not always differentiable since if we take the differentiable function to be I (or x), then the result is obviously not differentiable. So what I ask for is that when they do; why?

Answer (score 11):

Let $f,g\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and define $h_p,h_c\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as the product and the composition of $g$ and $f$, i.e.
$$h_p(x)=g(x)f(x),\qquad h_c(x)=g\circ f(x), \qquad \forall x \in \Bbb R.$$

Certainly:

- If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x_0\in \Bbb R$, then $h_p$ is differentiable at $c$.
- If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0\in \Bbb R$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$, then $h_c$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

As shown by the following examples, the reverse of these statements is not true.

**Examples:**

- $f,g$ not differentiable at $0$, and $h_p$ differentiable.
  Ex: $f(x)=g(x)=|x|$, and $h_p(x)=x^2$
- $f,g$ not differentiable at $0$, and $h_c$ differentiable.
  Ex: $f(x)=\begin{cases} x &\text{if }x\geq 0\\ 2x &\text{if }x<0\end{cases}, g(x)=f(-x)$, and $h_c(x)=2x$:
- $f$ not differentiable at $0$ and $g,h_p,h_c$ differentiable.
  Ex: $f(x)=|x|, g(x)=0$, and $h_c(x)=h_p(x)=0$:

Comment: But f is not even defined at zero, right?

Comment: $f\circ g$ is not defined at $0$...

Comment: After edit: No $f\circ f$ is not $x^2$

Comment: The left hand limit is $-3x^2$ which gives 0 and right is $3x^2$ which also gives 0 at 0.

Comment: Now it looks right

Comment: @Thomas yeah sorry for all these typos...

Comment: @quarkine ?¿ $f'(x) = \text{sign}(x)$ which is not defined at $0$.

Comment: @Surb :Oh right!... Anyway if we take the differentiable function to be x itself and take another to be any non-differentiable function then the composition is always non-differentiable. So what I asked was if it is always the case or not? And if not, then when and why?

Comment: @quarkine Attention if $f$ is not differentiable and $g$ is the identity, then $f \circ g=f=g \circ f$ is not differentiable. You can prove that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable. Have a look here: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142084/prove-that-the-composition-of-differentiable-functions-is-differentiable

Comment: @quarkine I tried to make my answer more clear, maybe it'll helps you.