# derivative of a function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is the same to derivative of $f(x)g(x)$ if $f,g,h$ have all same domains

Tags: calculus

assume it exists some h such that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for all x( suppose $f,g$ have same domain as h) and h(x) is differentiable in some c, does it imply that $f(x)g(x)$ are also differentiable in c and have equal derivative to $h(x)$ in c?

to prove it my idea is to use the definition of derivative and then using the fact $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for all x in the domain substitute $f(x)g(x)$ for $h(x)$ and $f(c)g(c)$ for $h(c)$, then by hypothesis that $h'(x)$ exist in c these 2 derivatives exist and are obviously the same.

Comment: Let $f(x)\neq 0$ be *non*-differentiable, and $g(x)=1/f(x)$, then $h(x)=1$ is differentiable. So it does not hold even if $f,g,h$ have the same domain.

Comment: @Surb what is the faulty assumption in my reasoning?

Comment: It is hard to say as you are not providing any rigorous proof. From what I can see, you are "substituting" $f(x)g(x)$ for $h(x)$ and $f(c)g(c)$ for $h(c)$, which in principle is fine if these functions are defined at $c$. However, I suspect you are also substituting $h'(x)$ with whatever expression involving $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$. But the latter can only be done if $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ exists in the first place (which may not be the case).

Comment: @Surb so eventually the result hold if and only if f and g are derivable in c or even in that case what i stated may still be false?  Anyaway thank you for your time

Comment: Well, if $h$ is differentiable, then it could be that $f,g$ are differentiable, neither $f$ nor $g$ are differentiable, or just one of them is differentiable. If $h$ is not differentiable, then at least one of $f$ or $g$ must be non differentiable (that is all what can be said). You may want to have a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/856412/154545 I will update my answer with discussion on the product

Comment: @Surb thank you very much

Comment: As promised, I have updated my answer in the duplicate post.